# Partial View in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

In Xamarin Android is there a functionality like Partial View of ASP.NET MVC where I can use and display multiple axml and place it to a (1) axml file?

Comment: Do you want to get `Main.axml` like this link?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-resource-basics?tabs=windows#referencing-resources-from-xml

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Sorry but I dont think using Resources will achieve loading different axml files to a (1) axml file.

Comment: Do you want to use `<include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>` like this link?https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>` to achieve the result.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/app_bg"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to know more details, Here is link.
https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder named "menu" or another good name that fits your work under the "Resources" folder then add all your partial views such as action bars, overflow menus or/and common messages and popup dialogs then include them as it is explained in the answer above. Good luck!